# How to handle features that are not always applicable in Neural Network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

While constructing the features I will be feeding to my neural network, I noticed that some features are not always applicable for a specific input.

For example, in the context of a price forecast model for household items, consider a feature that represents how many days have passed since the item has last been discounted by a retailer. However some items have never been discounted in the past so how do I got about handling this ?

Should I just pass 0 or is discarding such a feature better ?

Thank you !

Comment: Which treatment gives you better results for your NN's purpose?

Answer (score 2):

> a feature that represents how many days have passed since the item has last been discounted by a retailer

A default value suits better for this case, in a "initial case" all items would have 0 as the discount value.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that was the best solution too